# Finding who calls a system function

Tags: c++, debugging, ntdll

I have a C++ application, developed with VisualStudio 2015 (update 2).

Profiling with AMD Code XL shows that the program spends almost 20% of its time in the function `RtlUpcaseUnicodeToMultiByteN`, from the module `ntdll.dll`. Apparently it converts unicode tsrings to upper case.

As it makes no sense to spend that much time doing that, I need to know who is calling the function. 
Turns out it isn't easy.

What I'd want to do is set a breakpoint, then see the call stack. However, I cannot set it the usual way without the source code.

I tried Windbg, but the stack trace was essentially useless.

Then I found there [is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx) a way to set a "function breakpoint" in VisualStudio; but the program never did break; even though the "modules" window showed `ntdll.dll` as "symbols loaded" status.

What more can I do?

Comment: Shouldn’t your profiler give you the call stack?

Comment: Should it? I didn't think it would. I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: Most (all?) profilers do, in some form or another, since without a stack trace this information is completely useless (as you’ve yourself discovered).

Comment: Indeed it did! For future reference: right-click, "open in Call Graph".

Comment: need set breakpoint to RtlUpcaseUnicodeToMultiByteN and if "stack trace was useless" debug step by step until not found call source